# PyCharm fills up swap despite available RAM and then crashes when the swap fills up

Tags: ram, crash, swap

I am running PyCharm when I have about 11.8GB of free RAM and about 2.8GB of free swap. This program needs more than 2.8GB to run. When I start it, it slowly fills up the swap until it fills it up, and then it crashes.

`dmesg -T` doesn't show anything for today except for "perf: interrupt took too long" which is unrelated.

This leads me to believe when the program asks for memory, it is getting swap from the OS, and when it can no longer get any more memory from the OS, it crashes.

In the recent past, the program would reside in RAM instead of swap. It may be that I let the program sit in the background a lot, but the crashing only started today. It is also worth noting that yesterday, I started reading and writing around 40GB of 40,000 files, and even though that stopped, maybe it had some residual effects on system settings.

What is going on?

Comment: Why does the software even matter? I'll add it regardless.

Comment: You have a point. I have not even test if other programs do this.

Comment: Looks like Android Studio does not do the same, so it is related to PyCharm.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems I may have to let the program run in the background, because now pycharm is in RAM.

Comment: Is it possible there was a large cache for all those files in RAM that has cleared?

Comment: Can you find a way to replicate the problematic behavior? If you can reliably reproduce the behavior, it will be easier to identify the cause, which would make it easier to apply a solution.

Comment: What's the output for `free -m`?